# How to add elemts to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Prog1:

```
public class TestArrayList {

    ArrayList<TestVO> list=new ArrayList<TestVO>();
    TestVO test5=new TestVO();
    public ArrayList<TestVO> getArrayList2() {

        test5.setName("jagadeesh");
        test5.setPhnNo("123456789");
        list.add(test5);

        test5.setName("Prasana");
        test5.setPhnNo("987456321");
        list.add(test5);
        return list;

    }

}
```

Prog2:

```
public class TestVO {

    String name;
    String phnNo;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhnNo() {
        return phnNo;
    }
    public void setPhnNo(String phnNo) {
        this.phnNo = phnNo;
    }

}
```

prog3:

```
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestArrayList aList=new TestArrayList();

        ArrayList<TestVO> test=aList.getArrayList2();

        for (TestVO testVO : test) {

            System.out.println("name is: "+testVO.getName());
            System.out.println("name is: "+testVO.getPhnNo());
        }
    }

}
```

output:

```
name is: Prasana
name is: 987456321
name is: Prasana
name is: 987456321
```

while executing above program, I am not understaning why second element replacing first element also. please help me how to fix this??
problem adding elements to array list

Comment: because you are using the same object

Answer (score 1):

create a new object everything inside getArrayList2() {}
Something like this

```
public ArrayList<TestVO> getArrayList2() {
TestVO test5=new TestVO();
test5.setName("jagadeesh");
test5.setPhnNo("123456789");
list.add(test5);
TestVO test6=new TestVO();
test6.setName("Prasana");
test6.setPhnNo("987456321");
list.add(test6);
    return list;
}
```

Or

```
TestVO test =null;
public ArrayList<TestVO> getArrayList2() {

    test = new TestVO();
    test.setName("jagadeesh");
    test.setPhnNo("123456789");
    list.add(test);
    test = new TestVO();
    test.setName("Prasana");
    test.setPhnNo("987456321");
    list.add(test);
    return list;

}
```

When you do like what you are doing setting name phoneNo to the objectand adding the object  to the list the previous values get overridden

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the same object and adding it twice to the list so all (both) the object in the list will be the same one.
You should just create a new one for each round:

```
public ArrayList<TestVO> getArrayList2() {
    TestVO t = new TestVO();
    t.setName("jagadeesh");
    t.setPhnNo("123456789");
    list.add(t);

    t = new TestVO(); // Note the new object creation
    t.setName("Prasana");
    t.setPhnNo("987456321");
    list.add(t);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: logically speaking if you do like this you will get a compilation error saying variable t has already been defined in the scope

Comment: @SparkOn bad copy-paste, thanks for noticing! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using the same instance. (you are using test5 instance in both time. Therefore there is only one instance)

```
test5.setName("jagadeesh");
test5.setPhnNo("123456789");
list.add(test5);

test5.setName("Prasana");
test5.setPhnNo("987456321");
list.add(test5);
```

Instead of that create a new instance and add that to the ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Modify getArrayList2() as below:

public ArrayList getArrayList2() {

```
    test5.setName("jagadeesh");
    test5.setPhnNo("123456789");
    list.add(test5);

     test5=new TestVO();

    test5.setName("Prasana");
    test5.setPhnNo("987456321");
    list.add(test5);
    return list;

}
```

This might work as you expected.

When you add an Object to an ArrayList or any collection, it is not like that a new copy is created and inserted. The reference of the object is inserted. When any attribute of an object changed that inserted before in any List, you got the changes when you access them from the list. In your code, you added "test5" to list and then changed name and phnno. But you didn't created new object. So old one is changed. And You have two copy of same object on your list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding object references to your ArrayList<>, therefore you must create a new instance for each data record.

```
public ArrayList<TestVO> getArrayList2() {

    TestVO test5 = new TestVO();     // Create new instance 
    test5.setName("jagadeesh");      // Set name
    test5.setPhnNo("123456789");
    list.add(test5);                 // Add object reference to list

    test5 = new TestVO();            // Create new instance
    test5.setName("Prasana");        // Set name
    test5.setPhnNo("987456321");
    list.add(test5);                 // Add object reference to list
    return list;

}
```